# DoubleLinkedList Gets the Memory Location not the Node Value - Python

Tags: python, algorithm, linked-list

I am trying to make a Doubly LinkedList, but I am getting the memory location instead of the Node value. Appreciate the help

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

class Node:
  def __init__(self, num):
    self.next = None
    self.prev = None
    self.num = num

class DlinkedList:
   def __init__(self):
     self.start = None
     self.end = None
     self.size = 0 

   def addFirst(self, num):
     n = Node(num)

     if( self.start == None):
       self.start = n
       self.end = n
       print (self.start)
       print (self.end)
       print (self.size)
     else:
       n.next = self.start

d = DlinkedList()
print ("Add node 2")
d.addFirst(2)
print ("Add Node 1")
d.addFirst(1)
```

the output lools like the following which means that I am doing something wrong here.

I understand the code is not complete yet, but I am trying ti start little by little

The output of the code is:

```
Add node 2
<__main__.Node object at 0x7f0c61219940>
<__main__.Node object at 0x7f0c61219940>
0
Add Node 1
```

Comment: That is the default string representation of an object. If you want to change how it appears, you'll have to write your own `__str__(self)` or `__repr__(self)` methods

Comment: Nothing is wrong.  Just print off `self.start.num` and you'll get the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are missing some key steps here. You need to make sure you are incrementing your counter as well as linking in the new node to the front of your doubly linked list. Here is what I ended up with:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

class Node:
  def __init__(self, num):
    self.next = None
    self.prev = None
    self.num = num

class DlinkedList:
   def __init__(self):
     self.start = None
     self.end = None
     self.size = 0 

   def addFirst(self, num):
     n = Node(num)

     if(self.start == None):
       self.start = n
       self.end = n

       print (self.start.num)
       print (self.end.num)
       print (self.size)
     else:
       n.next = self.start
       self.start.prev = n
       self.start = n
     self.size += 1

d = DlinkedList()
print ("Add node 2")
d.addFirst(2)
print ("Add Node 1")
d.addFirst(1)

print(d.start.num, d.start.next.num, d.end.prev.num, d.end.num)
```

Example output from iPython

```
Add node 2
2
2
0
Add Node 1
1 2 1 2
In [3]: d.addFirst(3)

In [4]: print(d.start.num, d.start.next.num, d.end.prev.num, d.end.num)
3 1 1 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You're printing `self.start` and `self.end` which are of type `Node` and since `Node` doesn't have a `__str__` override, it just prints the memory location. What you want to do is print `self.start.num` and `self.end.num` or else add a definition for `__str__`:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.num
```